# Reference requence: scheme of complete homomorphisms of rank $r$ via blowups.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes, algebraic-stacks

I'm reading [these](https://www.impan.pl/swiat-matematyki/notatki-z-wyklado~/ngo.pdf) notes

where it states:

[image]

Referring to the construction of some kind of compactification of the stack of Drinfeld's Shtukas. What is this "well-studied scheme of morphisms via blowups" and what are any references? I don't even know what to search for it.

Comment: It looks like this is described in more detail in the 4 chapter/section of the notes. More broadly, it sounds like the notion of "complete linear map" comes into play, which I would suggest Googling.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I asked on Overflow which referred me to a paper of Lafforgue that explained it.